# How to pivot using multiple columns in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I am having trouble creating pivot table that follows the schema described below.
For example, with the following table (not all records are shown here):

| Route | Bus_Fare_Payment_Method | Total_Annual_Household_Income |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Route 1 | 10-Ride Pass | $15K To $19K |
| Route 1 | 10-Ride Pass | $15K To $19K |
| Route 1 | 10-Ride Pass | $25K To $29K |
| Route 1 | 10-Ride Pass | $60K Or More |
| Route 1 | Regular Cash Fare | Under $10K |
| Route 1 | Regular Cash Fare | Under $10K |
| Route 1 | Regular Cash Fare | Under $10K |
| Route 1 | Regular Cash Fare | Under $10K |
| Route 1 | Regular Cash Fare | Under $10K |
| Route 1 | Regular Cash Fare | Under $10K |
| Route 1 | Regular Cash Fare | Under $10K |
| Route 1 | Regular Cash Fare | Under $10K |
| Route 10 | 10-Ride Pass | $30K To $39K |
| Route 10 | 31-Day Adult | $10K To $14K |
| Route 10 | 31-Day Adult | $10K To $14K |
| Route 10 | 31-Day Adult | $10K To $14K |
| Route 10 | 31-Day Adult | $10K To $14K |
| Route 10 | 31-Day Adult | $15K To $19K |
| Route 10 | 31-Day Adult | $20K To $24K |
| Route 10 | 31-Day Adult | $20K To $24K |
| Route 10 | 31-Day Adult | $20K To $24K |
| Route 10 | 31-Day Adult | $20K To $24K |
| Route 101 | All Day Pass Reduced | Under $10K |
| Route 101 | Other | Under $10K |
| Route 101 | Reduced Fare | $10K To $14K |
| Route 101 | Reduced Fare | $25K To $29K |
| Route 101 | Reduced Fare | $30K To $39K |
| Route 101 | Reduced Fare | $40K To $49K |
| Route 101 | Reduced Fare | $60K Or More |
| Route 101 | Reduced Fare | $60K Or More |
| Route 101 | Reduced Fare | $60K Or More |
| Route 101 | Reduced Fare | Under $10K |
| Route 101 | Reduced Fare | Under $10K |
| Route 101 | Reduced Fare | Under $10K |
| Route 101 | Regular Cash Fare | $10K To $14K |
| Route 101 | Regular Cash Fare | $10K To $14K |
| Route 101 | Regular Cash Fare | $10K To $14K |
| Route 101 | Regular Cash Fare | $10K To $14K |

I would like to produce the following table:

| Route | Bus_Fare_Payment_Method | $10K To $14K | $15K To $19K | $20K To $24K | $25K To $29K | $30K To $39K | $40K To $49K | $60K Or More | Under $10K |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Route 1 | 10-Ride Pass |  | 2 |  | 1 |  |  | 1 |  |
| Route 1 | 31-Day Adult |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Route 1 | All Day Pass Reduced |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Route 1 | Other |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Route 1 | Reduced Fare |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Route 1 | Regular Cash Fare |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 8 |
| Route 10 | 10-Ride Pass |  |  |  |  | 1 |  |  |  |
| Route 10 | 31-Day Adult | 4 | 1 | 4 |  |  |  |  |  |
| Route 10 | All Day Pass Reduced |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Route 10 | Other |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Route 10 | Reduced Fare |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Route 10 | Regular Cash Fare |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Route 101 | 10-Ride Pass |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Route 101 | 31-Day Adult |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Route 101 | All Day Pass Reduced |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 1 |
| Route 101 | Other |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 1 |
| Route 101 | Reduced Fare | 1 |  |  | 1 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 3 |
| Route 101 | Regular Cash Fare | 4 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

I am able to create the following table with the query included below, but I am missing the Route field which I need as part of my output (as shown above).

```
SELECT [Bus_Fare_Payment_Method] "Bus Fare Payment Method", [Under $10k] 'Under $10k', [$10K to $14K] '$10K to $14K',[$15k to $19k] '$15k to $19k', [$20k to $24k] '$20k to $24k', [$25k to $29k] '$25k to $29k', [$30k to $39k] '$30k to $39k', [$40k to $49k] '$40k to $49k', [$50k to $59k] '$50k to $59k', [$60k or more] '$60k or more'
FROM   
(SELECT [Route], [Total_Annual_Household_Income], [Bus_Fare_Payment_Method]  
FROM [BCT_TDP_SURVEY_2018] where [Bus_Fare_Payment_Method] != '' ) p  
PIVOT  
(  
COUNT ([Route])  
FOR [Total_Annual_Household_Income] IN  
( [Under $10k], [$10K to $14K],[$15k to $19k], [$20k to $24k], [$25k to $29k], [$30k to $39k], [$40k to $49k], [$50k to $59k], [$60k or more] )  
) AS pvt  
ORDER BY pvt.[Bus_Fare_Payment_Method]
```

| Bus_Fare_Payment_Method | $10K To $14K | $15K To $19K | $20K To $24K | $25K To $29K | $30K To $39K | $40K To $49K | $60K Or More | Under $10K |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10-Ride Pass |  | 2 |  | 1 | 1 |  | 1 |  |
| 31-Day Adult | 4 | 1 | 4 |  |  |  |  |  |
| All Day Pass Reduced |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 1 |
| Other |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 1 |
| Reduced Fare | 1 |  |  | 1 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 3 |
| Regular Cash Fare | 4 |  |  |  |  |  |  | 8 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you could include a dbfiddle or something with the demo data that would be great.  But in the meantime, I think this should work?

I added a column "1 AS RC" to count against so you can get the Route column back out.  You can absolutely use multiple columns as the anchor for your pivot statements, you just need to use something else for the aggregate.

```
SELECT [Route]  
    , [Bus_Fare_Payment_Method] "Bus Fare Payment Method"
    , [Under $10k] 'Under $10k'
    , [$10K to $14K] '$10K to $14K'
    , [$15k to $19k] '$15k to $19k'
    , [$20k to $24k] '$20k to $24k'
    , [$25k to $29k] '$25k to $29k'
    , [$30k to $39k] '$30k to $39k'
    , [$40k to $49k] '$40k to $49k'
    , [$50k to $59k] '$50k to $59k'
    , [$60k or more] '$60k or more'
FROM (
    SELECT [Route]
        , [Total_Annual_Household_Income]
        , [Bus_Fare_Payment_Method]
        , 1 AS RC
    FROM [BCT_TDP_SURVEY_2018]
    WHERE [Bus_Fare_Payment_Method] != ''
    ) p
PIVOT(SUM(RC) FOR [Total_Annual_Household_Income] IN (
            [Under $10k]
            , [$10K to $14K]
            , [$15k to $19k]
            , [$20k to $24k]
            , [$25k to $29k]
            , [$30k to $39k]
            , [$40k to $49k]
            , [$50k to $59k]
            , [$60k or more]
            )) AS pvt
ORDER BY pvt.[Bus_Fare_Payment_Method]
```

Comment: It worked perfectly! I was also told that I could I achieve this by using conditional aggregation. Thanks a gain for your time and sharing your knowledge.

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you.  This https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/164835/which-is-faster-sumcase-or-cte-pivot seems to indicate that SQL uses conditional aggregation behind the scenes and well written versions of either perform equally well.  So use whichever syntax you are most comfortable with (I like PIVOT, I think it looks cleaner)